# Unable to use dot syntax for ruby hash

Tags: ruby, syntax, hash

I'm using `net/http` to pull in some json data from the Yahoo Placemaker API. After receiving the response I am performing `JSON.parse` on the response. This gives me a hash that looks like:

```
{"processingTime"=>"0.001493", "version"=>"1.4.0.526 build 111113", "documentLength"=>"25", "document"=>{"administrativeScope"=>{"woeId"=>"2503863", "type"=>"Town", "name"=>"Tampa, FL, US", "centroid"=>{"latitude"=>"27.9465", "longitude"=>"-82.4593"}}, "geographicScope"=>{"woeId"=>"2503863", "type"=>"Town", "name"=>"Tampa, FL, US", "centroid"=>{"latitude"=>"27.9465", "longitude"=>"-82.4593"}}, "localScopes"=>{"localScope"=>{"woeId"=>"2503863", "type"=>"Town", "name"=>"Tampa, FL, US (Town)", "centroid"=>{"latitude"=>"27.9465", "longitude"=>"-82.4593"}, "southWest"=>{"latitude"=>"27.8132", "longitude"=>"-82.6489"}, "northEast"=>{"latitude"=>"28.1714", "longitude"=>"-82.2539"}, "ancestors"=>[{"ancestor"=>{"woeId"=>"12587831", "type"=>"County", "name"=>"Hillsborough"}}, {"ancestor"=>{"woeId"=>"2347568", "type"=>"State", "name"=>"Florida"}}, {"ancestor"=>{"woeId"=>"23424977", "type"=>"Country", "name"=>"United States"}}]}}, "extents"=>{"center"=>{"latitude"=>"27.9465", "longitude"=>"-82.4593"}, "southWest"=>{"latitude"=>"27.8132", "longitude"=>"-82.6489"}, "northEast"=>{"latitude"=>"28.1714", "longitude"=>"-82.2539"}}, "placeDetails"=>{"placeId"=>"1", "place"=>{"woeId"=>"2503863", "type"=>"Town", "name"=>"Tampa, FL, US", "centroid"=>{"latitude"=>"27.9465", "longitude"=>"-82.4593"}}, "placeReferenceIds"=>"1", "matchType"=>"0", "weight"=>"1", "confidence"=>"8"}, "referenceList"=>{"reference"=>{"woeIds"=>"2503863", "placeReferenceId"=>"1", "placeIds"=>"1", "start"=>"15", "end"=>"20", "isPlaintextMarker"=>"1", "text"=>"Tampa", "type"=>"plaintext", "xpath"=>""}}}}
```

I am able to access elements by doing things like `jsonResponse['version']` but I am not able to do `jsonResponse.version`. Why is this?

Comment: I don't think Ruby supports that.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`Hash` does not have dot-syntax for it's keys. `OpenStruct` does:

```
require 'ostruct'
hash = {:name => 'John'}
os = OpenStruct.new(hash)
p os.name #=> "John"
```

*NOTE: Does not work with nested hashes.*

Comment: Only for one level of dots  os.name.firstname does not seem to work,  os.name returns a normal hash

Comment: This does not work for nested hashes and arrays. See whodabudda's answer below.

Answer (score 50):

OpenStruct will work well for a pure hash, but for hashes with embeded arrays or other hashes, the dot syntax will choke.  I came across this solution, which works well without loading in another gem:
https://coderwall.com/p/74rajw/convert-a-complex-nested-hash-to-an-object
basic steps are:

```
data = YAML::load(File.open("your yaml file"))
json_data = data.to_json
mystr = JSON.parse(json_data,object_class: OpenStruct)
```

you can now access all objects in mystr using dot syntax.

Comment: "Since both JSON and OpenStruct are in the Ruby Standard Library, we'll have no third-party dependencies."

Answer (score 17):

Ruby hashes don't work like this natively, but the [HashDot](https://github.com/adsteel/hash_dot) gem would work for this.

HashDot allows dot notation syntax use on hashes. It also works on json strings that have been re-parsed with `JSON.parse`.

```
require 'hash_dot'

hash = {b: {c: {d: 1}}}.to_dot
hash.b.c.d => 1

json_hash = JSON.parse(hash.to_json)
json_hash.b.c.d => 1
```

Comment: Nice gem! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to install any gems, you can try to use the Ruby's native `Struct` class and some Ruby tricks, like the [splat operator](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/).

```
# regular hashes
customer = { name: "Maria", age: 21, country: "Brazil" }
customer.name
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for {:name=>"Maria", :age=>21, :country=>"Brazil"}:Hash

# converting a hash to a struct
customer_on_steroids = Struct.new(*customer.keys).new(*customer.values)
customer_on_steroids.name
#=> "Maria"
```

Please note that this simple solution works only for single-level hashes. To make it dynamic and fully functional for any kind of `Hash`, you'll have to make it recursive to create substructs inside your struct.

You can also store the Struct as if it was a class.

```
customer_1 = { name: "Maria", age: 21, country: "Brazil" }
customer_2 = { name: "João",  age: 32, country: "Brazil" }
customer_3 = { name: "José",  age: 43, country: "Brazil" }

Customer = Struct.new(*customer_1.keys)
customer_on_steroids_1 = Customer.new(*customer_1.values)
customer_on_steroids_2 = Customer.new(*customer_2.values) 
customer_on_steroids_3 = Customer.new(*customer_3.values)
```

[Read more about Ruby Struct class.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html)

Comment: I was looking for an analog to C#'s anonymous type and this works great.

Answer (score 9):

Why not, you can do this via metaprogramming

```
module LookLikeJSON
  def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
    if has_key?(meth.to_s)
      self[meth.to_s]
    else
      raise NoMethodError, 'undefined method #{meth} for #{self}' 
    end
  end
end

h = {"processingTime"=>"0.001493", "version"=>"1.4.0.526 build 111113", "documentLength"=>"25"}
h.extend(LookLikeJSON)
h.processingTime #=> "0.001493"
```

Comment: interpolate string in single quote? : /   And using `stringify_keys!` to normalize the keys first.

Comment: Perhaps a smaller, single-line version of this: `Hash.define_method(:method_missing) { |*args| m = args.first; fetch(m, nil) || fetch(m.to_s, nil) || super(*args) }`

Answer (score 6):

That is a JavaScript feature, not a Ruby feature.  In Ruby, to use a "dot syntax", the object would need to respond to those methods.  Ruby hashes use the `#[](key)` method to access elements.

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna go ahead and piggyback off @whodabudda with this one liner

```
# example hash
hash = { some: [ {very: :deep}, {very: :nested}, {very: :hash} ] }

#one-liner to convert deep open
deep_open = JSON.parse(hash.to_json, object_class: OpenStruct)

#now you can do this sorcery!
deep_open.some.map(&:very)
=> ["deep", "nested", "hash"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in Rspec stubs will work too.

```
let(:item) { stub(current: 1, total: 1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If round-tripping JSON seems like too much overhead:

```rb
# Constructor like OpenStruct, but not open; and deep, not shallow
# Example: hash = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: 3 } }
#          obj = DeepStruct.new(hash)
#          obj.a # read
#          obj.b.c += 1 # read and write 
#          obj.x # error
class DeepStruct
  def initialize(hash)
    hash.each do |k, v|
      self.class.send(:attr_accessor, k)
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v.is_a?(Hash) ? DeepStruct.new(v) : v)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `Hash` doesn't have a `version` method.