# How to access Chewy results with the dot notation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chewy-gem

I'm using [Toptal's Chewy gem](https://github.com/toptal/chewy) to connect and query my Elasticsearch, just like an ODM.

I'm using [Chewy](http://][1]) along with Elasticsearch 6, Ruby on Rails 5.2 and Active Record.

I've defined my index just like this:

```
class OrdersIndex < Chewy::Index
  define_type Order.includes(:customer) do

    field :id, type: "keyword"

    field :customer do
      field :id, type: "keyword"
      field :name, type: "text"
      field :email, type: "keyword"
    end
  end
end
```

And my model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

The problem here is that when I perform any query using Chewy, the customer data gets deserialized as a hash instead of an Object, and I can't use the dot notation to access the nested data.

```
results = OrdersIndex.query(query_string: { query: "test" })
results.first.id
# => "594d8e8b2cc640bb78bd115ae644637a1cc84dd460be6f69"

results.first.customer.name
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Hash:0x000000000931d928>

results.first.customer["name"]
# => "Frederique Schaefer"
```

How can I access the nested association using the dot notation (`result.customer.name`)? Or to deserialize the nested data inside an Object such as a Struct, that allows me to use the dot notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the just-deserialized results to JSON string and deserializing it again with OpenStruct as an `object_class` can be a bad idea and has a great CPU cost.

I've solved it differently, using recursion and the Ruby's native `Struct`, preserving the laziness of the Chewy gem.

```
def convert_to_object(keys, values)
  schema = Struct.new(*keys.map(&:to_sym))
  object = schema.new(*values)

  object.each_pair do |key, value|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      object.send("#{key}=", convert_to_object(value.keys, value.values))
    end
  end

  object
end

OrdersIndex.query(query_string: { query: "test" }).lazy.map do |item|
  convert_to_object(item.attributes.keys, item.attributes.values)
end
```

`convert_to_object` takes an array of keys and another one of values and creates a struct from it. Whenever the class of one of the array of values items is a Hash, then it converts to a struct, recursively, passing the hash keys and values.

To presence the laziness, that is the coolest part of Chewy, I've used `Enumerator::Lazy` and `Enumerator#map`. Mapping every value returned by the ES query into the `convert_to_object` function, makes every entry a complete struct.

The code is very generic and works to every index I've got.

Answer (score 2):

try to use

```
results = OrdersIndex.query(query_string: { query: "test" }).objects
```

It converts query result into active record Objects. so dot notation should work. If you want to load any extra association with the above result you can use .load method on Index.

If you want to convert existing ES nested object to accessible with dot notation try to reference this answer. Open Struct is best way to get things done in ruby.

[Unable to use dot syntax for ruby hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356704/unable-to-use-dot-syntax-for-ruby-hash)

also, [this](http://robdodson.me/ruby-objects-and-dot-syntax/) one can help too

see [this](https://coderwall.com/p/74rajw/convert-a-complex-nested-hash-to-an-object) link if you need openStruct to work for nested object

Comment: It queries only final result object only. not the exact ES query

Comment: Convert it to ruby hash to openStruct object as hash does not have .dot syntax

Comment: it works with some modification check this 

mystr = JSON.parse(json_data,object_class: OpenStruct)

Comment: I have updated my final answer to work for the nested object. You can accept it. if it works for you.

Comment: I've proposed another solution. Seems to be more performatic.